# Can a cluster of galaxies be partially inside Hubble's sphere and partially out of the cosmological event horizon?

Tags: cosmology, event-horizon, observable-universe

Can a cluster of galaxies be partially inside Hubble's sphere and partially out of the cosmological event horizon? Let say we see only that part that moves in one orbital direction e.g. moving from left to the right?

Answer (score 1):

If "Hubble's sphere" and "cosmological event horizon" refer to the same horizon, then yes.

If not, then not. Because the Hubble length is 14.4 bly, the particle horizon is 46.9 bly, the event horizon is 16 bly, where bly means billion light years long. See [here for a list of cosmological horizons you could have chosen from.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_horizon)

The furthest galaxy observed, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GN-z11 is at a proper distance of 32 bly, outside of the Hubble sphere, but light from this galaxy reaching Earth today has only travelled 13.4 bly. I include this example to illustrate that we can see galaxies that emitted light in the past, but are now outside of our Hubble volume. The other complicating factor is that the Hubble sphere changes over time as the Hubble parameter changes.